# black and white (preferably with pattern) barchart using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using following data and code to make a grouped barchart in ggplot2:

```
mm = structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("one", "two", "three"
), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
15L, 14L, 10L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("name", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

mm
   name variable value
1     A      one     1
2     B      one     5
3     C      one     6
4     D      one     9
5     A      two     5
6     B      two     7
7     C      two     8
8     D      two     9
9     A    three    15
10    B    three    14
11    C    three    10
12    D    three     9

ggplot(mm) + geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=variable), stat='identity', position="dodge")
```

[image]

However, it is colored and I need black and white plot (with either grey or shaded bars). I tried following but was not successful:

```
ggplot(mm) + geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=variable), stat='identity', position="dodge")+theme_classic()

ggplot(mm) + geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=variable), stat='identity', position="dodge")+theme_bw()

ggplot(mm) + geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value, group=variable), stat='identity', position="dodge")
```

How can I get black and white (grey or preferably patterned with different styles as in: http://support.sas.com/kb/45/663.html (click on results tab)) barchart with ggplot? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried `scale_colour_grey()` like in the following link: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/scale_grey.html

Comment: @Harpal `scale_fill_grey` for the bars.

Comment: @James: scale_fill_grey() works well. Any way it can make differently styled shadings?

Comment: @James oooops, you are right!

Comment: @mso, in what way do you mean styled? Patterns?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the bars in black/white/grey? Or are you saying that you want all bars in black and the background in white?

Comment: Using patterns as in: http://support.sas.com/kb/45/663.html (click on results tab) and http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67273/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0relmtk2s8ac9n13bnmicsgsmwu.htm

Comment: I don't think fill patterns are possible due to grid's limitations, see Hadley Wickhams comments https://www.google.de/search?q=ggplot+hatching+bar+fill

Comment: I seem to have finally found something common which is not possible in R (yet)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have mesh effects on bars, that seems to be really challenging. I have not personally seen ggplots figures with mesh effects on bars. The only thing I could think was to draw lines on top of bars using `geom_segment()`. I did not create mesh bars, but I created a bar with vertical lines. Since I had to draw so many lines, I just wanted to show how much work one would have in this way. It would be great if we can use mesh bar chart with ggplot. If there is no such thing, I would try to deliver same/similar visual effects in different ways.

```
ana <- ggplot(mm,aes(x=name, y=value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position="dodge") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "grey", "grey")) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1.85, y = 0, xend = 1.85, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1.9, y = 0, xend = 1.9, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1.95, y = 0, xend = 1.95, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 0, xend = 2, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 2.05, y = 0, xend = 2.05, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 2.1, y = 0, xend = 2.1, yend = 7)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 2.15, y = 0, xend = 2.15, yend = 7)) 
ana
```

[image]